# Drop-down menu item is not select-able if it is styled right side with in the menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to style drop-down menu similar to following image

[image]

I have achieved this with boot-strap pull right but I am not able to select or highlight the Logout option if I hover the mouse left of the Logout option. It is highlighting if I hover the mouse on or near to the Logout text.

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li>
        <div>Menu</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>&#9660;</b></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu available-applications">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1 </a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2
            </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 3 </a>

            </li>
            <li style="float: right;">
                <a href="#">Logout </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/565ce2aw/)
Does any one have any idea?

Comment: Would you mind posting a JSfiddle or Bootply?

Answer (score 2):

Using pull-right floats the element to the right and makes it not take up the full width. Instead, just set the element's css text-align property.

You can do this by using the text-right class in bootstrap:

```
<li class="text-right"></li>
```

Or by setting the property manually:

```
<li style="text-align:right"></li>
```

Comment: You can use the built in text-right utility class. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment